# How to change logo size in sticky header on different screen sizes with JS?

Tags: javascript

I would like to change the logo size in the sticky header when the screen is scrolled 100 viewport height. I want to give different sizes for different screen sizes.

I tried to use the code given below. It worked on screen size wider than 1600px, but on smaller screen sizes did not work. (in the code at the moment 500px scrolling is given)

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {

  if ($(window).width() > 1600) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
      document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "170px";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "220px";
    }
  } else if ($(window).width() > 577) {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
      document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "100px";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "170px";
    }
  } else {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500) {
      document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "10px";
    } else {
      document.getElementById("logo").style.width = "130px";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.menu-wrapper .logo img {
  max-height: 220px!important;
  @media screen and (max-width: $breakpoint-xl) {
    width: 170px!important;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: $breakpoint-lg) {
    width: 130px!important;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: $breakpoint-xs) {
    width: 110px!important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not change it in your CSS media queries? (Just add/remove a class using JS when you pass your scroll position and leave the sizing down to CSS)

Comment: Does it absolutely have to depend on scrolling some element or the document? Because your question title doesn't mention that and I want to edit it because the question itself strongly suggests that rendered logo dimensions should depend on scrolling offset (position of the document in the view).

Comment: I accomplished with CSS by targeting the sticky class. I tried before as well, but somehow did not work, thats why I started to work on JS solution. I tried it again with CSS and now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by removing conditional operators from js

```
window.onscroll = function() {
   document.getElementById("logo").classList.toggle("large", document.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 500)
}
```

Then add appropriate styles in css for `#logo.large` element

Edit: Using `scrollingElement` for getting current offset, setting class with `classList.toggle`

Comment: Even better, use `classList` instead of `className` for a more generic solution, and the `toggle` function available on the `classList` object: `...classList.toggle("large", document.body.scrollTop > 500 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 500)` (absense of `large` implies "small" and nothing then interferes with other class names). Also, why not use [`scrollingElement`](http://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-document-scrollingelement): `classList.toggle("large", document.scrollingElement.scrollTop > 500)`?